# what is the difference in this 2 code?

Tags: c++, differential-equations

I wrote two codes for solving a differential problem, both using predictor corrector approach.

The first one is for solving differential system as well, so basically the it uses a vector `y` of size equal to the number of the equation to solve in the system, so this one basically is overwritten each step and doesn't store the step before.

The second one instead uses a vector of size equal to the number of steps, so it's easy to control which elements we are using.

I wrote two different (but basically identical) functions: one used for the first routine, and the second one for the second routine

I did a lot of debug but I don't understand what I did wrong.

Here are the two different versions of the solver:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <functional>
# include <vector>
# include <string>
# include <cmath>
# include <fstream>
# include <valarray>


using namespace std;


std::vector<std::function<const double(const double t , std::valarray<double> u)>> func ;


auto f2      = [](double t , double u) {return -20*u+20*sin(t)+cos(t) ; } ;

auto numFun  = [](double t , std::valarray<double> u) {return -20*u[0]+20*sin(t)+cos(t) ; } ;


int main (){

      double t0 = 0.0 ;
      double tf = 2.5 ;
      double dt = 0.01;


      const int N = (tf-t0)/dt;

      func.push_back(numFun);

      auto& f  =    func ;

      double t1 ;
      std::valarray<double> y1 ; 
      y1.resize(func.size()) ;   // size = 1  
      std::valarray<double> yp1 ; 
      yp1.resize(func.size()) ;  // size = 1


      std::vector<double> t2(N+1)  ;
      std::vector<double> y2(N+1)  ;
      std::vector<double> yp2(N+1) ;



      std::vector<double> u(1);
      u.at(0) = 1.0 ;

      t1  = t0 ;

      for(auto i=0; i< u.size() ; i++)
      {  
         y1[i]= u.at(i);
         yp1[i] = u.at(i);   
      }


      ofstream fn("output1.dat", ios::out);



      for(auto i=1 ; i <=N ; i++ )
      {

         fn << t1 << " " ;
         for(auto j =0 ; j < y1.size() ; j++ )
           fn << y1[j] << " " ;
         fn << endl ;

         for(auto j=0 ; j < y1.size() ; j++)
         {
            yp1[j] = yp1[j] + dt * f[j](t1 , y1) ;      

            y1[j] += dt/2 * ( f[j](t1 , y1) + f[j]( t1+dt , yp1 ));

         }
         t1+=dt ;    
      }
      fn.close();

/* --------------------          Vector version      --------------------------------- */      

      ofstream fn2("output2.dat", ios::out);

      t2.at(0) = t0 ;

      y2.at(0) = u.at(0) ;
      yp2.at(0) = u.at(0) ;


      fn2 << t2.at(0) << " " ;
      fn2 << y2.at(0) << " " ;
      fn2 << endl ;

      for(auto i=1; i <= N  ; i++ )
      {
         t2.at(i) = t2.at(i-1) + dt ;

        // Predictor step (Exp Euler) 

         yp2.at(i) = y2.at(i-1) + dt * f2(t2.at(i-1), y2.at(i-1)) ;  

         y2.at(i) = y2.at(i-1) + dt/2 * ( f2(t2.at(i-1), y2.at(i-1)) + f2(t2.at(i), yp2.at(i)) ) ;


         fn2 << t2.at(i) << ' ' << y2.at(i) << " " ;

         fn2 << endl;    
      }

      fn2.close();



  return 0;
}
```

I got this two different result in the output file : 
[image: this]

Comment: Which result is the correct one?

Comment: output2.dat , so the second solver

Comment: the first paragraph is a wall of text and it's difficult to follow

Comment: Please do not add SOLVED to the question (I removed it), mark the answer [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) instead.

Comment: You just replaced one error with the next, there should be no `yp1` on the right side. Now the graph does not correspond to the code. You will get a question corresponding to the accepted answer if you use a coupled 2D system, as the first variant still mixes the update of the state vector with the computation of the update.

Comment: …and do not post comments on answers as a part of the question. Use the comment box below the answer. The answer’s author won’t be notified otherwise. Rolled back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use 3 vector in this way !

```
         for(t=t0() ; t < tf() ; t+= dt()  )
         {
           f << t << ' ' ; 
           for(auto i=0 ; i< u.size() ; i++) 
               f << u[i] << " " ; 
           f << std::endl ;

           for( auto i=0 ; i < u.size() ; i++)        
           {      
                  up[i] = uc[i] + dt() * rhs.f[i](t , u) ;   


                  uc[i] += dt()/2 * ( rhs.f[i](t , u) + rhs.f[i]( t +dt() , up ) ); 

                   u[i] = uc[i] ;
           }             

         }
```

So basically the predictor variable have to be `uc[i] + ...` and could not be `+=` like in the standard Euler formulation (in this case he wrote `yp1[j]` = `yp1[j] + ...` ) instead of `yp1[j] = y[j] + ...`

Comment: Could you reformat this code to be readable, and then explain what it's doing, and how that solves the problem?

Comment: This still does not help, as the changed `u[0]` corresponding to `t+dt` will be used in the computation of `up[1]` where `u` is expected to contain the values at time `t`. What has the `uc` to do in the computation of `up`, it does not contain any useful value at that point.

Answer (score 3):

For the first method to work for vector valued ODE, you will need to separate the three steps into three loops corresponding to the vector operations in the second method. Note that the second method contains an implicit intermediate vector in the update of `y1` as the right side is first fully computed using the old value of `y1` before copyng it into `y1`.

```
  for(auto i=1 ; i <=N ; i++ )
  {

     fn << t1 << " " ;
     for(auto j =0 ; j < y1.size() ; j++ )
       fn << y1[j] << " " ; 
     fn << (exp(-20*t1) + sin(t1)) << " ";
     fn << endl ;

     for(auto j=0 ; j < y1.size() ; j++)
     {
        yp1[j] = y1[j] + dt * f[j](t1 , y1) ;      

     }
     for(auto j=0 ; j < y1.size() ; j++)
     {
        yc1[j] = y1[j] + dt/2 * ( f[j](t1 , y1) + f[j]( t1+dt , yp1 ));
     }
     for(auto j=0 ; j < y1.size() ; j++)
     {
        y1[j] = yc1[j];
     }
     t1+=dt ;    
  }
```